# Entity Framework 6 and MySQL, model first

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a problem using **Entity Framework 6** with **MySQL** and doing so using **model/database-first** technique in **ASP.NET C# MVC 3**.

The current situation is that I’m getting the error:

```
Keyword not supported.
Parameter name: metadata
```

The metadata is specified in the connection string in the web.config –file:

```
<add name="SiteNameContainer" 
  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models. SiteName.csdl|
    res://*/Models. SiteName.ssdl|
    res://*/Models. SiteName.msl;
    provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    provider connection string='server=127.0.0.1;
    user id=fire;password=fire_db;
    database=fire_dotnet'" 
  providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

I tried to remove the metadata-section in the connectionString, but then its saying that the keyword “provider” is not supported, and then “provider connection string” not supported.

I also have these 2 sections in my web.config file:

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
            type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, 
            MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
    <clear />
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
        invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
        description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" 
        type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, 
        MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

I have references to MySQL Net-connector 6.8.3 files (MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, MySql.Web).

My requirments are that I must use **MySQL** and **Entity Framework 6**, and the changelog for the .NET connectior says that 6.8.x added support for MySQL.

I’m out of ideas, hopefully someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html yet? The example app.config there is significantly different than what you posted. Full disclosure: I've never used EF with MySQL.

Comment: Yes, however I'm using Model first so I need the metadata mappings

Comment: out of curiosity, which VS are you using?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you may be using the wrong providerName in your connection string, it should be `System.Data.EntityClient`.

Here's how I finally got my model-first code to work with MySQL and what my app.config looks like:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyEntities"
       connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Entity.Model.csdl|res://*/Data.Entity.Model.ssdl|res://*/Data.Entity.Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=localhost;User Id=dbadmin;Password=password;Initial Catalog=database_name;&quot;"
       providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

In case that doesn't work, here's the entityFramework section. You'll notice the codeConfigurationType attribute I used in the following section. It is adds dependency resolvers for MySQL, but there are other ways of doing it which you can read about in the [MySQL: EF 6 Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) documentation.

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Aha! Just the one line fixed it for me `<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>`
Thanks!